# WordPress v5.4.2 escapes the content of Edit Attachment > Description field

Tags: the-content

I updated WordPress to v5.4.2 and now the content on the screen Edit Attachment, field Description is being HTML escaped so I cannot use HTML in this field.

The problem seems to be caused by this line in wp-admin\includes\media.php

```
<?php wp_editor( format_to_edit( $post->post_content ), 'attachment_content', $editor_args ); ?>
```

In previous versions it was:

```
<?php wp_editor( $post->post_content, 'attachment_content', $editor_args ); ?>
```

Since `format_to_edit` is being called the expected result is to get escaped HTML, but I wonder why other themes I tested return the correct output (i.e. un-escaped HTML).

Comment: The content has to be escaped or it can break the editor. The proper solution is to not escape it on output. If it's working in some themes and not others, check how those themes are _outputting_ the content.

Comment: I reported this issue and it is now an approved bug. More details here. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/50692